# Cannot find Explore option in Servers tab (Eclipse Juno SR2)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I downloaded the new Eclipse Juno SR2. After creating a server in the Servers tab, I cannot find the 'Explore' option (when you click on the server name and use your right mouse button). It is a JBoss 7.1 server by the way. Does any one know if the 'Explore' option has been removed or is there a different way of getting to it?

Comment: Do you still have *all* of the plug-ins you had before switching to SR2 installed and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find Explore but I can use 'Show In' > 'File Browser' to achieve the same thing.